# Automatically resize rows of a grid contained in another grid

Tags: wpf

I have a grid within the first column of another grid and want the rows of the inner grid take on the same height of the rows of the parent grid. The idea is that the inner grid can contain descriptions that I want to be able to hide (but stay aligned with the rows of the parent grid, because these descriptions are associated with certain questions in the parent grid). A WPF ColumnDefinition doesn't have a Visibility property :(

The code I have thusfar:

```
    <Grid ShowGridLines="true" Name="gridje">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="row0"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="row1"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="row2"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" ShowGridLines="true">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=row0, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=row1, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=row2, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Joepie</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Joepie</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">Klaasje daskljf askldfas dfasjkl dfhklasjdfh askljdfh askljdfh h askljdfh klasdfh alsjkdfh askldfh askljfh alsdjkfh asklfh </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">Klaasje daskljf askldfas dfasjkl dfhklasjdfh askljdfh askljdfh h askljdfh klasdfh alsjkdfh askldfh askljfh alsdjkfh asklfh</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="textb" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding ElementName=row0, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
    <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,173,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

The strange thing is that in design mode in VS2010 everything works fine, but once running all the actual height properties stay zero.

Any help on this would be appreciated. And maybe using some other WPF control to accomplish this is also no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) -property will help you. With this, you can synchronize widths and heigths of Grid-elements.
An example on how to use it is contained in the msdn-article.

Comment: I will try that out. And: what about using one grid with the descriptions in the first column and setting the size to zero. I thought of this in the car while driving ;) but wonder if I didn't tried that already...

Comment: Setting the size to zero causes a very tiny scrolbar to appear on the right because it still tries to display the content in the "hidden" column...So that's not an option.

Comment: @Joep Greuter: Not sure if I understand your problem right, but why not inserting the info-textblocks in the first column, set the widht of the first column to "Auto" and then hide/show the info-textblocks accordingly (via binding). If I understand your problem right, this will behave as you desire. Then you can also get rid of the child-grid, what makes the design easier. By the way, I have read that binding to Active[Width|Height] can slow down layout-performance. Not sure if this is a fact, but I can imagine. Therefore I would make some tests before going into production.

Comment: @Joep Greuter: If you want to try with the IsSharedSizeScope, I would try separate the grids. Don't make them parent/child, align them besides each other, I could imagine that this will work better.

Comment: I go for gettting rid of the child grid. Then looping through all UIElements in the first grid column and set them to Visibility.Collapsed and set the size of the column to zero. Thanx for your tips. The second comment is also a good idea. I'll mark your answer as correct although I go for another option I think. I'm trying them out right now ;)